# Vue - Problem when passing props with a colon into the component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-props

I want to pass TailwindCSS pseudo-classes to a child component. However, I get an error message (*Parsing error. Unexpected token :...*).

Here is my code:

```
<cartImage :images="p.images" :classNames="hover:grow hover:shadow-lg" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you just need to pass a static value to the `classNames` prop. So you only need to remove the colon like this:

```
<cartImage :images="p.images" classNames="hover:grow hover:shadow-lg" />
```

Comment: that was the solution. thanks. i will accept the answear in 5 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

When you do this :

```
:classNames="hover:grow hover:shadow-lg"
```

it will think of `hover:grow hover:shadow-lg` as a valid statement or variable - which will fail at this point.

---

If you want to pass a `String` you have **2 Options** :

Either with a static prop

```
classNames="hover:grow hover:shadow-lg"
```

Or you wrap the input inside 2 single quotes `'...'` :

```
:classNames="'hover:grow hover:shadow-lg'"
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the two possibilities.  this answer is also acceptable.